# How to create graph dependency between internal projects in sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

I know that it is possible to generate graph of library dependencies in sbt, something like:

```
>sbt dependencyDot
[info] Wrote dependency graph to 'target/dependencies-compile.dot'
> dot target/dependencies-compile.dot -Tpng -o /tmp/dependencies-compile.png
```

Anyway, the question is: is it possible to create graph containg [only] internal projects? I mean how to include dependencies like:
`dependsOn(ProjectRef(file("../../some_module/scala"), "some_module_utils"))` on graph?